# How can I detect that it's the same file in this custom method call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn JavaScript React.

I have this state:

```
  state = { files: [] };
```

And when I call this method with the same prop two times the `test` is always true when it should be false in the second call:

```
  someMethod() {
    const { newFile } = this.props;
    const { files } = this.state;
    let test = files.every((file) => newFile.size !== file.size);

    if (test) {
      const newList = files.concat({ newFile });
      this.setState({
        files: newList,
      });
    }
  }
```

In The code above the `newFile` looks like this;

```
{
  source: "react:Dashboard",
  id: "uppy-/object/object/1612029328210-2r-10-2t-image/jpeg-42985-1612029045180",
  name: "[object Object]1612029328210",
  extension: "",
  meta: {
    relativePath: null,
    name: "[object Object]1612029328210",
    type: "image/jpeg",
  },
  type: "image/jpeg",
  data: {
  },
  progress: {
    percentage: 0,
    bytesUploaded: 0,
    bytesTotal: 42985,
    uploadComplete: false,
    uploadStarted: null,
  },
  size: 42985,
  isRemote: false,
  remote: "",
  preview: undefined,
}
```

How can I detect that it's the same `newFile` and by so not adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `files.concat({ newFile })`? I think you meant to do `files.concat(newFile)` directly without creating an object with a `newFile` field that contains the file itself.